# How to use DrawingImage by URL in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, vector

I want to create service, for generate XAML icons. Perhaps this will be useful for quickly creating a high-quality UI on WPF. I only write the name of the icon, and the XAML code is returned to me

Today, my service looks like this:
[image]

Do you think it is possible to use this XAML by attaching it by the URL?

Something like this:

```
<Image Source="http://localhost:49424/delete" />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Not like this. Your XAML should create the DrawingImage, not an Image control. Then you should use XamlReader to parse the XAML, probably in a Binding Converter. IMO it doesn't make much sense to have a service to create a vector icon.

Comment: If it even is actually a good idea to get your vector icons from a webservice, I'd hide it in a singleton class that gets them once and caches them, then bind to properties of that. Or a markup extension.

Comment: And don't forget to load some defaults in case of a network error.